# Bind context on vue js method with PIXI JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pixi.js

Is it possible to bind context on method? I made an pixi graphic:

`var square = new PIXI.Graphics();`

Then I call my method `this.onDragMove` and bind `square`.

```
square
    .on('pointermove', this.onDragMove.bind(square));
```

But when I log `this` it still logs the vue component.

```
onDragMove() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log('Object is moving')
},
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible?

Comment: You don't seem to have ever reassigned `this.onDragMove` to `this.onDragMove.bind(square)`

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: did you do: `this.onDragMove = this.onDragMove.bind(square)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods):

> All methods will have their `this` context automatically bound to the Vue instance.

You cannot rebind the `this` context of methods defined on a Vue instance, for the same reason that the following code does not work as expected:

```js
function foo() {
  return this;
}

const X = {};
const Y = {};

const fooX = foo.bind(X);
const fooY = fooX.bind(Y);  // Attempting to bind an already bound function

console.log(fooX() === X);  // true
console.log(fooY() === X);  // true
console.log(fooY() === Y);  // false
```

You can access the original unbound function through [`$options`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options):

```js
square
    .on('pointermove', this.$options.methods.onDragMove.bind(square));
```